# Updating campaign member status in SF when email invitation is sent from MC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign-member

We have a working connector between SF and MC.
When an invitation is sent via email from Marketing Cloud to campaign members in Salesforce, we want the status to be updated from "Will be sent" to "Invitation sent".

It doesn't happen even thought we have this "[Campaign member integration](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/campaign_member_integration/)" covered.

I am generally not working in SF and I wonder - what am I missing?

Would it work to update the member status from the actual email (via ampscript)?

Thankful for some help

Comment: Are you using Person Accounts?

Comment: What Object is your Status field on? All depends what object you are wanting to update... Is it the standard Status field or a custom status field?

Comment: HI it is custom fields and it is not Person Accounts

Answer (score 1):

AMPscript may be the solution to your problem.

I guess that you are using the Contact (or Lead) IDs as Subscriber Keys (because you are using the connector to connect with SF).

Maybe you can use the AMPscript function [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/updatesinglesalesforceobject52/) to update the campaignMember. You need the ID of the corresponding campaignMember in order to update it (which you may retrieve with a lookup from an lead/contact ID in the campaignMember synchronized data extension).

```
%%[
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", "campaignMember ID here",
"Status", "Invitation sent"
)
]%%
```

*I was not able to test the code as we do not have a Salesforce environment which uses campaignMember. So some changes may be needed*.

A list of all Salesforce objects can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm), including [campaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, The code provided above can update the status while the email is being sent. Is there a way to update campaign member with statuses like 'Opened', 'Clicked', 'Bounced' etc. which happens after the email has gone out.

Comment: I think that updating open/click/bounce is not possible with AMPscript because it renders only at the moment of sending or viewing the online version